# How to size an external Javascript generated image from within my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image-resizing

I only have control of my HTML page, but it includes a call to get an image from an external JavaScript. The resulting image size is too big and I need to change it from within my HTML to an specific width and height.

The Javascript call on my page is just:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://xxxxx.js">
</script>
```

What html should I add to set the resulting image to widht=600 and height=180?

Comment: Please add the generated html so we can tell you how to target it.

Comment: css: `img {width:600px}` or js `img.width=600`

Comment: how about writing styles in your html? You can give width and height for images like `image{ width: 100px; height: 100px; }`

Comment: With Jquery, you could just get the image and set the css style.  Or with regular javascript, you could do imgHandle.style.width='600px'.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Adding <div id="xxx" class="xxx" style="width: 600px; height: 180px;">

Answer (score 0):

If you using bootstrap..apply  the IMG-responsive class to IMG tag. That should resize gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

Adding a div tag and setting width and height with style, before the script did it. My code now looks like this:

```
<div id="xxx" class="yyy" style="width: 600px; height: 180px;">

<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://zzz.js" >
</script>
```